# How to manipulate a collection in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, object, lodash, javascript-objects

I am trying to get an object from another javascript object. I have written the following code to group:

```
function execute(args) {
  const networkHospitals = args[0];
  cummulatedArray = _.groupBy(networkHospitals, "cityName");
  console.log(cummulatedArray);
}
```

Here's the sample output that I get from the above code:

```
{
  Trichy: [
    {
      hospitalName: 'asd',
      address_1: 'Friday',
    }
  ]
}
```

But I want to return the data in this format:

```
{
  "key": "Tirchy",
  "value": [{
    "hospitalName": "asd",
    "address_1": "Friday"
  }],
}
```

Here's the input data:

```
"networkHospitals": 
[{
  "hospitalName": "abc",
  "address_1": "Friday",
  "cityName": "Trichy"
}],
```

I would be really grateful, if you can guide me how to manipulate this JSON data that I am getting.

Comment: What is the input data?

Comment: What have you tried? It looks like you know what you're doing, but it sounds like you're trying to get other people to program your stuff for you.

Comment: What if there is one more property in the input object. Then how will it store in final result?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

Comment: Hello Kushagra, please add the input date that you are using. Furthermor what is the `arrayCityName` for? it seems like you create it but never use it afterwards again, as it's scope is only in the execute function. if you do not need it for this usecase, just remove it from the code that you are posting here. otherwise it is just confusing.

Comment: @OriDrori I have added the input data

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After grouping by `cityName`, map the groups, and create an object for each group. If needed map the values, and omit the `cityName` property from each object.

```js
const networkHospitals = [{"hospitalName":"abc","address_1":"Friday","cityName":"Trichy"}]

const result = _.map(
  _.groupBy(networkHospitals, 'cityName'),
  (val, key) => ({
    key,
    value: val.map(o => _.omit(o, 'cityName'))
  })
)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js" integrity="sha512-WFN04846sdKMIP5LKNphMaWzU7YpMyCU245etK3g/2ARYbPK9Ub18eG+ljU96qKRCWh+quCY7yefSmlkQw1ANQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

Answer (score 3):

This is how lodash does group by, if you want different shape you can do simple transformation at the end

```
identity

collection = [
    {cityName: "A", hospitalName: "Hospital A1", address: 'adr A1'},
    {cityName: "A", hospitalName: "Hospital A2", address: 'adr A2'},
    {cityName: "A", hospitalName: "Hospital A3", address: 'adr A3'},
    {cityName: "B", hospitalName: "Hospital B1", address: 'adr B1'},
    {cityName: "C", hospitalName: "Hospital C1", address: 'adr C1'},
    {cityName: "C", hospitalName: "Hospital C2", address: 'adr C2'},
]
groupped = _.groupBy(collection, 'cityName')
console.log(Object.keys(groupped).map(
  cityName => ({key: cityName, value: groupped[cityName]})
));
```

it will give you this:

```
[
  {
    key: 'A',
    value: [
      {
        address: 'adr A1',
        cityName: 'A',
        hospitalName: 'Hospital A1'
      },
      {
        address: 'adr A2',
        cityName: 'A',
        hospitalName: 'Hospital A2'
      },
      {
        address: 'adr A3',
        cityName: 'A',
        hospitalName: 'Hospital A3'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    key: 'B',
    value: [
      {
        address: 'adr B1',
        cityName: 'B',
        hospitalName: 'Hospital B1'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    key: 'C',
    value: [
      {
        address: 'adr C1',
        cityName: 'C',
        hospitalName: 'Hospital C1'
      },
      {
        address: 'adr C2',
        cityName: 'C',
        hospitalName: 'Hospital C2'
      }
    ]
  }
]
```